# Redirect sound from PC to PC

Tags: windows-7, networking, audio, speakers

In my home network I have laptop and desktop computers. Speakers are connected to the desktop, but I want to manage music from my laptop.
Is there any other way to redirect sound from laptop to desktop?

Comment: Not an answer, but PulseAudio supports network audio transport. However, there's no Windows driver for it yet.

Comment: ORLY? http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/AboutPulseAudio#SupportedOperatingSystems

Comment: @mhambra: Daemon and tools, yes. Driver, no.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of your default player and install Foobar or anything alike with remote-control plugin. It is quite a normal linux practice for lots of nix players like mpc; and now it's web 2.0, home easy networks and windows.

http://forums.naimaudio.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/8772903417/m/9862900827

Comment: Yes, that is the sane approach +1.

Comment: Yes, the "I want to package up all the audio out of my machine to transport it to another to actually make noise" is silly when there are music players that can present you with a simple web-page based interface...

Answer (score 1):

[NAS](http://www.radscan.com/nas.html) can do that and they claim there is a way to make it run under Windows.

I haven't used it there, but I guess the setup will be hairy. Also, NAS seems pretty much dead after pulseaudio entered the stage.